# Proper way of tracing distributed requests through Azure Function Apps

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am experimenting with Node.js and the application insights SDK in two separate function apps. Nodejs is just what I am comfortable with to quickly poc, this might not be the final language so I don't want to know any language specific solutions, simply how application insights behaves in the context of function apps and what it expects to be able to draw a proper application map.

My goal is to be able to write simple queries in log analytics to get the full chain of a single request through multiple function apps, no matter how these are connected. I also want an accurate (as possible) view of the system in the application map in application insights.

My assumption is that a properly set `operation_id` and `operation_parentId` would yield both a queryable trace using kusto *and* a proper application map.

I've set up the following flow:
[image: intended flow]

`Function1` only exposes a HTTP trigger, whereas `Function2` exposes both a HTTP and Service Bus trigger.

The full flow looks like this:

1. I call Function1 using `GET http://function1.com?input=test`
2. Function1 calls Function2 using REST at `GET http://function2.com?input=test`
3. Function1 uses the response from Function2 to add a message to a service bus queue
4. Function2 has a trigger on that same queue

I am mixing patterns here just to see what the application map does and understand how to use this correctly.

For step 1 through 3, I can see the entire chain in my logs on a single `operation_Id`. In this screenshot the same operationId spans two different function apps:
[image: distributed rest tracing]

What I would expect to find in this log is also the trigger of the service bus where the trigger is called `ServiceBusTrigger`. The service bus *does* trigger on the message, it just gets a different operationId.

To get the REST correlation to work, I followed the [guidelines from applicationinsights npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights#azure-functions-example) in the section called *Setting up Auto-Correlation for Azure Functions*.

This is what `Function1` looks like (the entrypoint and start of the chain)

```js
let appInsights = require('applicationinsights')
appInsights.setup()
    .setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
    .setDistributedTracingMode(appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C)
    .start()

const https = require('https')

const httpTrigger = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    const response = await callOtherFunction(req)
    context.res = {
        body: response
    }
    context.log("Sending response on service bus")
    context.bindings.outputSbQueue = response;
}

async function callOtherFunction(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(`https://function2.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=${process.env.FUNCTION_2_CODE}&input=${req.query.input}`, (resp) => {
            let data = ''

            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk
            })
    
            resp.on('end', () => {
                resolve(data)
            })
    
        }).on("error", (err) => {
            reject("Error: " + err.message)
        })
    })
}

module.exports = async function contextPropagatingHttpTrigger(context, req) {
    // Start an AI Correlation Context using the provided Function context
    const correlationContext = appInsights.startOperation(context, req);

    // Wrap the Function runtime with correlationContext
    return appInsights.wrapWithCorrelationContext(async () => {
        const startTime = Date.now(); // Start trackRequest timer

        // Run the Function
        const result = await httpTrigger(context, req);

        // Track Request on completion
        appInsights.defaultClient.trackRequest({
            name: context.req.method + " " + context.req.url,
            resultCode: context.res.status,
            success: true,
            url: req.url,
            time: new Date(startTime),
            duration: Date.now() - startTime,
            id: correlationContext.operation.parentId,
        });
        appInsights.defaultClient.flush();

        return result;
    }, correlationContext)();
};
```

And this is what the HTTP trigger in Function2 looks like:

```js
let appInsights = require('applicationinsights')
appInsights.setup()
    .setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
    .setDistributedTracingMode(appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C)
    .start()

const httpTrigger = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    context.res = {
        body: `Function 2 received ${req.query.input}`
    }
}

module.exports = async function contextPropagatingHttpTrigger(context, req) {
    // Start an AI Correlation Context using the provided Function context
    const correlationContext = appInsights.startOperation(context, req);

    // Wrap the Function runtime with correlationContext
    return appInsights.wrapWithCorrelationContext(async () => {
        const startTime = Date.now(); // Start trackRequest timer

        // Run the Function
        const result = await httpTrigger(context, req);

        // Track Request on completion
        appInsights.defaultClient.trackRequest({
            name: context.req.method + " " + context.req.url,
            resultCode: context.res.status,
            success: true,
            url: req.url,
            time: new Date(startTime),
            duration: Date.now() - startTime,
            id: correlationContext.operation.parentId,
        });
        appInsights.defaultClient.flush();

        return result;
    }, correlationContext)();
};
```

The [Node.js application insights documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) says:

> The Node.js client library can automatically monitor incoming and outgoing HTTP requests, exceptions, and some system metrics.

So this seems to work for HTTP, but what is the *proper* way to do this over (for instance) a service bus queue to get a nice message trace and correct application map? The above solution for the `applicationinsights` SDK seems to only be for HTTP requests where you use the `req` object on the context. How is the `operationId` persisted in cross-app communication in these instances?

What is the proper way of doing this across other messaging channels? What do I get for free from application insights, and what do I need to stitch myself?

**UPDATE**
I found this piece of information in the [application map documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=javascript#composite-application-map) which seems to support the working theory that only REST/HTTP calls will be able to get traced. But then the question remains, how does the output binding work if it is *not* a HTTP call?

> The app map finds components by following HTTP dependency calls made between servers with the Application Insights SDK installed.

**UPDATE 2**
In the end I gave up on this. In conclusion, Application Insights traces *some* things but it is very unclear when and how that works and also depends on language. For the [Node.js docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) it says:

> The Node.js client library can automatically monitor incoming and outgoing HTTP requests, exceptions, and some system metrics. Beginning in version 0.20, the client library also can monitor some common third-party packages, like MongoDB, MySQL, and Redis. All events related to an incoming HTTP request are correlated for faster troubleshooting.

I solved this by taking inspiration from [OpenTracing](https://github.com/opentracing/specification/blob/master/specification.md). Our entire stack runs in Azure Functions, so I've implemented logic to use `correlationId` that passes through all processes. Each process is a span. Each function/process is responsible for logging according to a structured logging framework.

Answer (score 0):

Since I got a notification this has been getting some views, I thought I'd expand on the pattern I've been using since then.

As mentioned I am using service bus queues to communicate between functions. All calls to the backend go through Azure APIM, and there I use `context.Request` and attach that as a header to requests before they reach the backend. This enables tracing all the way from receiving the request in APIM and through each service involved.

I then use structured logging in dotnet, where the logs are sent to Application Insights:

```cs
// Everything in this scope will log CorrelationId in customDimensions in app insights
using var scope = _logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["CorrelationId"] = message.CorrelationId
});
_serviceBusClient.SendAsync(NewMessage(), message.CorrelationId, ct);
```

By sending the message to the next service using the same correlationId, it becomes traceable as long as you send the logs for each service to the same instance of Application Insights, or solve that some other way. Each service must also initiate a logging scope as above the first thing they do as they receive the message.

Once the logs are in Application Insights, you can query it like this:

```
let correlationId = 'correlationId';
traces
| extend
    CorrelationId = tostring(coalesce(customDimensions.prop__CorrelationId, customDimensions.CorrelationId)),
| where CorrelationId == correlationId
| sort by timestamp asc
```

If logging from an in-process Function App, the property will be `customDimensions.prop__CorrelationId`.
If logging from an isolated Function App, the property will be `customDimensions.Correlation`. If you have a mix of these (like I had), use `coalesce` to get the first non-null value.